# Associate one emitter with a specific curve

Tags: particles, bezier-curves

Is there any way to make an emitter follow a specific curve path and be affected by other curves that are on the same layer?

The Idea is to simulate air flowing through a group of openings in a model: so far the only way I could do that is by moving every emitter and its curve to a dedicated layer but that is a nightmare, because the number of curves I need is not small.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards to all

Hani

Comment: Hi! tbh, I can't properly understand what you are trying to achieve, and how. Can you perhaps show better the issue with an example, an image? Are you using this https://www.blender.org/manual/ru/physics/force_fields/types/curve_guide.html#curve-guide ?

Comment: If I'm getting this correctly, you are trying to emit particles that you should follow **several** different paths, yes? - have you tried a curve guide force field on the paths (physics tab)? The field 'catches' particles and forces them to follow a path.

Comment: Hi @squarespiral, you are correct. I'm in fact using curves but they result in particles flowing between the curves rather than on the curves. if I place the emitter and the curve on separate layers they function as I want but that is time-consuming due to the number of curves I need hence my question about a way to associate a curve to a specific emitter so that the particles would flow from the emitter on the associated curve without being affected the force field of nearby curves.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that particles from an emitter are following a curve guide force field do the following:

1. Make a simple emittor object e.g. a cube
2. Change to edit mode, select one vertex and add this single vertex to a vertex group
3. In the particle systems tab, scroll down to Vertex Groups and select the vertex group with the single emitter vertex - this will cause the particles to be emitted from just this one vertex
4. Place the emitter vertex close to the curve guide path
5. (Optional) Adjust the force field settings to control the effective distance of the field (to avoid overlaps with other fields)
6. If you need multiple emitters and paths you can parent the emitter to the path and duplicate as needed.

Setting this up, can be a bit tricky sometimes, since it can happen, that particles drop out of the force field, but with a bit of fiddling it can be done.

[image: Emittor with single-vertex vertex group and particles following a curve guide.]

I used this technique to create the arrows in this video: http://rheologic.net/en/urban-wind-assessment#wind-effects